# Sending bulk emails using SMTP

Tags: python, email, smtp, nodemailer, smtplib

I have a web application that can send emails with PDF attachments. The basic idea is that the users upload excel files with few fields and these fields are converted to PDF and it is attached and mailed to the email provided in the excel file. The excel file looks like this

```
To-addr         field1       field2        field3
abc@gfc.com       $2        London           UK
bcd@asdsa.com     $3        New York         USA
...
```

Based on each row a PDF is generated and mailed to the email. So when the user uploads this file 2 PDFs is generated and email to each email respectively.

Users can register on the website using their email, it might be gmail, google workspaces, outlook or any other. And when registering we using their smtp and app password to authenticate emails ( like smtp.gmail.com for gmail, mail.outlook.com for outlook etc). Once the users mail is authenticated they can start uploading files.

The issue we are facing is that gmail account has hourly and daily limits on number of emails sent. The excel files might have more than 3000 rows so that the number of emails send will be 3000 at a single time. So when the account reaches limit we get an error in python saying

```
raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (421, b'4.7.0 Connection expired, try reconnecting. f17sm17741593wrt.18 - gsmtp')
```

I guess this error message is appearing as the limit is reached (the number of emails sent is 855 as opposed to the limit said as 500/day) also it might be due to the long time of the whole process (it showed this error after 42 mins from the beginning of the process, I give a 1 min pause after every 20 emails so that the limit is not reached).

I see different websites like calendly and zoho send emails from my email by inserting SPF and DKIM entry to the domain, I am not sure how those work and does the limit apply when using like this. If anyone can help me guide how to send emails by adding these entry, it is highly appreciated. RIght now in the program I use SMTP lib.

```
s = smtplib.SMTP(smtp, port)
s.starttls()
s.login(fromaddr, password)
....
s.sendmail(fromaddr, buyer_email, text)
```

One thing I need is that the email must be sent from the user's email id itself (the email they used to register). It can't be like username@somthing.com and keeping a cc to the user's actual email.

Also, will services like SendGrid can be helpful for me? I will have multiple users from different mail servers joining my website. Can creating my own SMTP server help me? Will creating something like that enable users to register my website and link to my smtp and send emails from the email address they registered like gmail.com, outlook.com, companyname.com (might be hosted in Microsoft exchange, google workspaces, other any other).

Comment: An own SMTP server is not trivial to configure right, If you make a mistake, it will not work correctly, or you may be targetted by spammers or other servers might refuse to accept mail from you. And even a perfect setup might be not good enough. Beware of "IP address reputation". It drives me crazy on my backup Internet connection. Gmail simply does not accept emails from the IP address pool belonging to my provider and I cannot do anything to fix it.

Comment: As you are just sending emails out, using a mail service is easier and way more comfortable. As you are getting an `Connection expired` error, did you try to drop the connection and reconnect after each 20 emails ?

Comment: Yea I realized the connection expiry error is when it gets 1 hour. So I make a re-login every 30 mins. Can't really get above the daily limit of 2000 emails.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer can you suggest one mail service to send emails out?